# 2 HDMI 1080p monitors from 1 usb c port

Tags: usb, hdmi, video-adapter

I have the 15 inch MacBook Pro 2016, is there a way to plug in 2 hdmi displays into 1 port.

Answer (score 3):

Technically this is possible. The trick, however, is finding the adaptor you will need to achieve it. I've seen many USB-C to HDMI adaptors on the market, but I don't recall seeing a USB-C to dual HDMI adaptor.

On the other hand, some people have achieved connecting two displays to a single USB-C port using a couple of different connectors. By this I mean they have purchased a USB-C to multiple port adaptor and then connected one HDMI display to the HDMI port, and a second HDMI display to one of the other ports through a second adaptor cable. I've generally seen this done in one of two ways:

- Using a DVI to HDMI adaptor, with the DVI end connected to the DVI port on the USB-C to multiple port adaptor and the HDMI end into the display
- Using a USB to Video adaptor, with the USB end connected to the USB port on the USB-C to multiple port adaptor and the DVI end into the display

However, your mileage in doing so may vary. I would ensure that if you go down this path that you're purchasing your adaptors/cables from somewhere you can return them if they don't do the job. Of course, if you can find a USB-C to Dual HDMI port adaptor, that should make things a lot easier.

**EDIT**

Another option may be using a USB-C hub (or the like) that has additional USB-C ports and then using two USB-C to HDMI adaptors plugged into those.

However, you will need to ensure that any such USB-C ports are not limited to only data transfer, charging, etc and that they will support output to a display. This is also true if you opt for a USB to Video adaptor.

Comment: That Is what I am thinking if I could find a product that has 4 usb c ports on it it should work I believe usb c supports daisy chaining. The trick however is all the hubs on the market seem to give usb 3 connections I am trying to find 1 with usb c ports

Comment: Yes, unfortunately most do only provide USB-C to USB 3 connections, but I have seen USB-C to USB-C ones (although they're usually multiple port models that do something like USB-C to HDMI & USB & SD Card etc). One example is the [OWC USB-C Dock](https://www.owcdigital.com/products/usb-c-dock/usb-c-dock-specs) - here's a [review](http://www.macworld.com/article/3041375/hardware/owc-usb-c-dock-review-opens-up-a-macbooks-possibilities.html). Whatever you do, just make sure that any additional USB-C ports actually support outputting to a display (many may only support data transfer/charging).

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not recommending the OWC USB-C Dock as I haven't used it so can't personally verify how good it is or whether it will do what you need. But it may be able to so it's one you should check out.

Comment: Yea, I did find that except it is rather expensive. best I found so far is [Belkin USB C Hub](http://www.belkin.com/us/p/P-F4U090/). However it doesn't have power pass through which totally defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy a USB Type-C to HDMI and a HDMI doubler, overall you can get these two for around $10.

I found these two to reccomend for you:

[Doubler](https://www.google.com.au/aclk?sa=l&ai=DChcSEwjR0J-tja_QAhUMA4YKHdFdDU0YABAK&sig=AOD64_1QxUOtbm-AodZFASYpTAtgxyTZIg&ctype=5&q=&ved=0ahUKEwjTgJutja_QAhUUR2MKHRmSAvkQwzwIJg&adurl=)

[Coverter](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=usb%20c%20to%20hdmi&safe=active&client=safari&sa=X&tbas=0&bih=672&hl=en-au&biw=1024&tbs=vw:l,p_ord:p,mr:1&tbm=shop&prmd=sivn&srpd=18328100880144218718&prds=num:1,of:1,epd:18328100880144218718&ved=0ahUKEwivx82nja_QAhUKHGMKHXKRDX4QgjYItQQ)

It would best to double check your options though.

Comment: A doubler would cause it to mirror the display on two monitors this is not correct. OP is looking for the ability to use two displays with one port.

Comment: But the doubler is there as an addition to the converter, best to keep it as an option IMO for other people who see the answer.